# How to get the first record from multiple months

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Placements table which keeps track of employees and their points per month.

I am trying to work out how to get the employee that finished in first place for each of the months.

I've tried something like this

```
create_table "placements", :force => true do |t|
 t.integer  "employee_id"
 t.date     "month"
 t.integer  "points"
end

@previous_winners = @placements.includes(:employee).order('points DESC').first
```

I think I might need to loop through all months?

Comment: *first place* means ?

Comment: Sorry I had  it ordered by 'months DESC' when it should have been 'points DESC'. So first place would be record with most points

Comment: (0..11).inject([]){|sum, m| sum << Placement.where(month: m).order('points DESC').first} month indexes are now same as array: January = 0, so winner of January = @placements[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'GROUP BY' works a little differently in PostgreSQL than in MySQL. What you are looking for is rails/ruby equivalent for the following SQL expression:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (month) month,points, employee_id
FROM placements
order by month, points DESC
```

In rails controller, you can get the above using:

```
@placements.select('DISTINCT ON (month) month, points, employee_id').where('YOUR_CONDITION').order('month, points DESC')
```

This is just an example on how to group in PostgreSQL, cater it to your needs.

PS: 'DISTINCT ON' is the trick here :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group` to group the top scores by month. Something like this should work:

```
@previous_winners = @placements.includes(:employee).group(:month).
  order('points DESC').map(&:employee)
```

This query returns the placement with the highest points value per month including the associated employee, then the map function returns the employee for each record.

This answer presupposes that the placement records for each month have the exact same date

[EDIT]

This answer does not work at all on postgres, and I don't think it actually returns the right results on MySQL at all! Here is a slightly kludgey version which should work (but will run a DB query for each month)

```
@previous_winners = @placements.distinct.pluck(:month).map do |month|
  @placements.includes(:employee).where(:month => month).
    order('points DESC').first.employee
end
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/52e55/1) is an SQL fiddle with the schema as described in the question if anyone wants to play around with it

Comment: This looks right. I'm getting a postgresql group_by error though. I didn't include that in the question so I will mark correct when I figure out the error and see that it works

Comment: Would I add .first to the end of the statement?

Comment: that would only give you the winner of the first month

Comment: Ok so how would I get all previous winners?

Comment: I'm using Postgresql so I get the following error: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "placements.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "placements".* FROM "placements" INNER JOIN "employee...

Comment: can you post the actual query sent to the DB?

Comment: SELECT "placements".* FROM "placements" INNER JOIN "employees" ON "placements"."employee_id" = "employees"."id" WHERE "employees"."business_id" = 43 GROUP BY month ORDER BY points DESC

Comment: Hmm this works on MySQL, there seems to be a difference in how the two DBs deal with GROUP BY clauses. Give me a few mins and I'll try and come up with something that should work

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that to get the previous month

```
from = Time.now.beginning_of_month - 1.month
to = from.end_of_month
```

Then you can add them to you query.

```
@previous_winners = @placements.includes(:employee).where('month BETWEEN ? AND ?', from, to).order('points DESC').first
```